# main method not executed python3

Tags: python, pyspark, python-3.6

I have this program that count the words in a sample.txt:

```
import os

from operator import add
from pyspark import SparkContext

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/usr/local/spark"
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6"

print("Hello World") #This is printed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonWordCount")
    lines = sc.textFile("sample.txt", 1)
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
        .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(add)
    output = counts.collect()
    for (word, count) in output:
        print("%s: %i" % (word, count))

    sc.stop()
```

but it seems the program does not run the if sentence where the main is. I am new programming with python, is there any errors in the code?

This is the output when I execute the code (note that "Hello World" is printed and the code is compiled correctly):
[image]

Comment: Adding a few `print`s, especially in the `if`-block can help to understand what happens. My guess: `output` is empty when reaching the `for`-loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for the response, I added some prints just after declared the if, but they do not appear in the output so I guesss the if-block is not executed at all

Comment: You can try (1) to add a `print(__name__)` or better  `print(repr(__name__))` before the `if` to see the value of `__name__` and (2) to start the script from command line without PyCharm

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks again, now it enters the if-block but, as you said, it does not execute the for loop... why is that? I already run this code using other version of python and I did not have any issues